# Webpack config extend

Tags: webpack

I have 2 projects sitting next ot each other.

```
/projectA
 |
 ----- /client
/projectB
 |
 ----- /client
```

I have /projectA/webpack.config.js inside /projectA that compiles all files to projectA/public/javascripts/generated.
How do i create /projectB/webpack.config.js that will compile files inside /projectB/client and output them to /projectA/public/javascripts/generated?

Here is my /projectA/webpack.config.js:

```
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const path = require('path');
  const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
  const urlrewrite = require('postcss-urlrewrite');

  const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

  console.log('Current NODE_ENV is', NODE_ENV);

  const isDev = NODE_ENV === 'development';
  const isMobile = process.env.MOBILE_DEVICE_BUILD || false;
  const localIdentName = '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:8]';

  const moduleRegexp = /node_modules\//;

  var plugins = [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en|ru|kk/),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'react-vendor-bundle.es6.js' }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV)
    })
  ];

  var loader = [];

  if (process.env.DEV_SERVER) {
    loader.push('webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080', 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server');
    plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
  }

  loader.push('./loader.jsx');

  const postcssPlugins = [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: [
        'last 3 versions',
        'ie >= 11',
        'ios >= 8',
        'android >= 4.4',
      ]
    })
  ];

  if (isMobile) {
    postcssPlugins.push(
      urlrewrite({
        imports: false,
        properties: ['background', 'content'],
        rules: [
          {from: /\/(public\/)/, to: '$1'},
        ]
      })
    );
  }

  const clientPath = __dirname + '/client';

  module.exports = {
    context: clientPath,
    entry: {
      loader: loader,
      vendor: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'react-bootstrap',
        'intl',
        'classnames',
        'underscore',
        'moment',
        'lodash',
        'sprintf-js'
      ],
      alseco: './alseco/index.js',
      admin: './admin/index.jsx'
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "/public/javascripts/generated",
      filename: "[name]-react-app-bundle.es6.js",
      publicPath: "/public/javascripts/generated"
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: moduleRegexp,
          loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory']
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          exclude: moduleRegexp,
          loaders: [
            'style',
            'css?modules&url=false&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=' + localIdentName,
            'csso',
            'postcss'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
        }
      ]
    },

    node: {
      fs: 'empty'
    },

    devtool: false,

    resolve: {
      extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx', '.css' ]
    },

    plugins: plugins,

    postcss: () => postcssPlugins,

    watch: isDev,

    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 100
    }
  };
```

Comment: Create a normal webpack config file, the only difference is going to be the output dir, you just have to point to where you want...

Comment: The thing is that /project A is main entry and 80% of js modules are located there. I created normal webpack config file in /project B directory. Is there a way to point webpack to both directories (/project A and /project B to build all js files into bundles and output them to /project A or /project B directory)?

Comment: you can only output to one directory given 1 single config file. What you can do is create 2 entrypoints on config file that is located on A. That will result in another bundle file that is going to be referring to B. Then you can copy that to wherever you want... that is the only option